# Cancel the AddThis Wordpress plugin on certain posts

Tags: php, wordpress, addthis

I have a Wordpress site that utilizes multiple custom post types to achieve different goals. I also use the AddThis plugin to append social sharing buttons to the top of the posts. However, I have one type of custom post that I do not the plugin to append the AddThis sharing buttons to. Is there a way to hook into the AddThis plugin to get it to return false or something given a certain condition?

Maybe something like:

```
if($post_type === "no-addthis"){
     addthis_plugin_hook(false);
}
```

I totally realize that's not a valid way to do it, but does anyone know of something similar?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will remove all **AddThis** filters operating on the current post:

```
if( get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'your-post-type' ) {
    remove_filter('the_content', 'addthis_display_social_widget', 15);
    remove_filter('the_content', 'addthis_script_to_content');
    remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'addthis_display_social_widget_excerpt', 11);
    remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'addthis_late_widget', 14);
    remove_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', 'addthis_remove_tag', 11, 2);
}
```

I'd advise running this code right before any call to `the_content()` or `the_excerpt()` ( or similar function prefixed with `get_` ) in your custom post type template.

**Note:** I haven't tested this and I've never used the AddThis plugin. I just peeked at the source code just now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Newest version I do the following in functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_addthis' );
function remove_addthis(){
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'addthis_add_content_filters');
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me with the latest WP/AddThis versions. To be fair though, I didn't have time to go debug it - it may be a very simple tweak - but I only needed the fix in one simple place so using the `get_the_content()` trick worked better for me.

Comment: My bad for not including the plugin version in the response. This answer is from 2014, so they most probably changed the filter name.